# quickblox error when login, android

Tags: android, facebook, quickblox

I'm using quickblox for a chat on android platform, with facebook auth,
I do these steps such

```
1)QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(..,..,..)
2)QBAuth.createSession(this, QBQueries.QB_QUERY_AUTHORIZE_APP)
3)SmackAndroid.init(this)
```

4)facebook login and get a accesstoken

```
5)QBUsers.signInUsingSocialProvider(QBProvider.FACEBOOK, accessToken, null, this)
6)QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser
```

but i have a error: (error when login: SASL authentication failed)
I don't know why.
can you help me?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with Chat login

```
6)QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser
```

If you do facebook login - you should use qb token as a password for Chat 
http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Password

For example:

```
// init test user
qbUser = new QBUser();
qbUser.setId(ApplicationConfig.testUserID1);
try {
    qbUser.setPassword(BaseService.getBaseService().getToken());
} catch (BaseServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time figuring out the issue. In my case I was using ChatService class instead of QBChatService for FB/Twitter login.