# SASL authentication failed Quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox, sasl

I am you using quickblox and im tryna authenticate the chat.. with this code

```
QBChatService.getInstance().loginWithUser(myapp.getQbUser(), MessageReader.this);
```

and at the end i get this error why?

```
SASL authentication failed
```

any help around here.....

Comment: There is a similar post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24547380/quickblox-error-when-login-android

Comment: i do not think so because, the other post uses facebook auth, and i am using direct authentication with a quickblox user..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user's password is wrong

print user entity  **myapp.getQbUser()** before chat login and check user ID and password